# How to do this query against MySQL database table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I was given a task to show the CPU usage trend as part of a building process which also do regression test.

Each individual test case run has a record in the table RegrCaseResult. The RegrCaseResult table looks something like this:

```
id   projectName  ProjectType  returnCode  startTime   endTime           totalMetrics

1    'first'      'someType'   16           'someTime' 'someOtherTime'   222
```

The RegrCaseResult.totalMetrics is a special key which links to another table called ThreadMetrics through ThreadMetrics.id.

Here is how ThreadMetrics will look like:

```
id   componentType   componentName   cpuTime   linkId

1    'Job Totals'    'Job Totals'    'totalTime' 34223
2    'parser1'       'parser1'       'time1'     null
3    'parser2'       'generator1'    'time2'     null
4    'generator1'    'generator1'    'time3'     null
------------------------------------------------------
5    'Job Totals'    'Jot Totals'    'totalTime' 9899
...
```

The rows with the compnentName 'Job Totals' is what the totalMetrics from RegrCaseResult table will link to and the 'totalTime' is what I am really want to get given a certain projectType. The 'Job Totals' is actually a summation of the other records - in the above example, the summation of time1 through time3. The linkId at the end of table ThreadMetrics can link back to RegrCaseResult.id.

The requirements also states I should have a way to enforce the condition which only includes those projects which have a consistent return code during certain period. That's where my initial question comes from as follows:

I created the following simple table to show what I am trying to achieve:

```
id   projectName  returnCode

1    'first'    16
2    'second'   16
3    'third'    8
4    'first'    16
5    'second'   8
6    'first'    16
```

Basically I want to get all the projects which have a consistent returnCode no matter what the returnCode values are. In the above sample, I should only get one project which is "first". I think this would be simple but I am bad when it comes to database. Any help would be great.

I tried my best to make it clear. Hope I have achieved my goal.

Comment: How many of these records do you have?

Comment: A number to the nearest power of ten was the answer I was looking for. Tens? Thousands? Hundreds of quadrillions?

Comment: 'third' is also consistent, according to the present definition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an easy way:

```
select projectname
from table t
group by projectname
having min(returncode) = max(returncode);
```

If the `min()` and `max()` values are the same, then all the values are the same (unless you have `NULL` values).

EDIT:

To keep `'third'` out, you need some other rule, such as having more than one return code.  So, you can do this:

```
select projectname
from table t
group by projectname
having min(returncode) = max(returncode) and count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: It's unclear as to whether 'third' should be included in the results - but a good idea though!

Comment: Well then... I feel dumb all of a sudden.  I guess it really is that simple. +1

Comment: Third should be included too.

Comment: `min(returnCode) = max(returnCode)` and `count(distinct(returnCode)) = 1` . Aren't they the same?

Comment: @cppcoder . . . They are similar in functionality.  `count(distinct)` is typically more computationally expensive than `count()`, `sum()`, `min()`, or `max()` because the database has to remember lists of things.

Answer (score 1):

```
select projectName from projects  
    group by projectName having count(distinct(returnCode)) = 1)
```

This would also return projects which has only one entry.
How do you want to handle them?

**Working example**:    http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7338/8

Comment: Are you asking a different question?

Comment: Please update your question. I can update my answer based on that. I do not see any cpu consumption in your table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works too but I can only accept one. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this with `Not Exists`:

```
Select  Distinct ProjectName
From    Table   A
Where   Not Exists
(
    Select  1
    From    Table   B
    Where   B.ProjectName = A.ProjectName
    And     B.ReturnCode <> A.ReturnCode
)
```

I'm not sure exactly what you're selecting, so you can change the `Select` statement to what you need.

Comment: Not exists is an expensive operation and if there is a huge number of operations this may not be feasible query.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT COUNT(ProjectName) AS numCount, ProjectName FROM (
  SELECT ProjectName FROM Foo
  GROUP BY ProjectName, ReturnCode
) AS Inside
GROUP BY Inside.ProjectName
HAVING numCount = 1
```

This groups all the ProjectNames by their names and return codes, then selects those that only have a single return code listed.

SQLFiddle Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c52b6/11/0